# How to add a button in header when condition is met while the component is being loaded?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My React Native (0.59) app uses react navigation (3.11) for routing mechanism. A `GroupStack` is created as below in `App.js`:

```
const GroupStack = createStackNavigator({
  Group: {
    screen: GroupWithSelf,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        title: 'Group',
        headerRight: (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Icon 
                name="plus" 
                size={30} 
                //color={} 
                type='octicon' 
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("NewGroup")}
                />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
     }}
  },

  NewGroup: {
    screen: NewGroupWithSelf,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'New Group',
    },
  },
  RemoveGroup: {
    screen: RemoveGroupWithSelf,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Remove Group',
    },
  },
  Groupmember: {
    screen: GroupmemberWithSelf,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        title: 'Group Member',
     }}
  },
  NewGroupmember: {screen: NewGroupmemberWithSelf},
  RemoveGroupmember: {screen:RemoveGroupWithSelf},
});
```

What I need to do is when `Groupmember` is loaded, add a `+` icon to the header based on if the user is an `admin` or not. Here is the `static navigationOptions` defined in component `Groupmember`:

```
 export default class Groupmember extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
      if (this.props.navigation.state.params.role === "admin") {
        return {
          headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Icon 
                  name="plus" 
                  size={30} 
                  //color={} 
                  type='octicon' 
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("NewGroupmember", {group_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.group_id})}
                  />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
       }
      };
    };
  ....
```

The problem is that there is no `+` is added and the `static navigationOptions` is ignored when `Groupmember` is being loaded. I understand that if I add this `navigationOptions` to `GroupStack` definition, the `+` sign will be shown whenever `Groupmember` is loaded. But this is not what I want. The `+` is added if the user is an `admin` when `Groupmember` is being loaded. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is :

1. Add a button to header and add a condition to when will that button will be shown to the user.Try rendering that in a function like `showButton = () =>{}`
2. It would be something like : `loading === true && this.showButton()`

Comment: What I did try was to move the `static navigationOptions` from component to `GroupStack` in `App.js`.. and the `+` shows successfully. After clicking `+`, the app did land in `NewGroupmember` component. But the problem is that params `group_id` is undefined and did not get passed in. The value of `group_id` is present when the component is being loaded and there is no value for `group_id` when `GroupStack` is defined.. Do you have a code example of what you are recommending to do?

Comment: Move the navigtionOptions to GroupStack with logic to control the hide/show of the button. Also pass the params as if it is in the component. This works so far.